# WinUI - Need help binding a child item for a NavigationView

Tags: winui-3

I'm trying to create a 2 level navigation using dynamic data via binding similar to

- Sports Car

  - Mustang
  - Ferrari
- Family Car

  - Flintstone Mobile
  - Mini Van

Using the code in the Microsoft documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.navigationviewitem.menuitemssource?view=winui-2.8

I want to change the data type of Children from Category to Car
public class Car { public string CarName {get; set;} }

When I click to expand a menu item, the application blows up and I don't really have any idea why.  System.ArgumentException("Value does not fall within the expected range.").  There is no stack trace.

Any help is appreciated.  Here is my template.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="NavigationViewMenuItem" x:DataType="local:Category">
        <NavigationViewItem Content="{x:Bind Name}" MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind Cars}">
            <NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Car">
                    <NavigationViewItem Content="{x:Bind CarName}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </NavigationViewItem.MenuItems>
        </NavigationViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might be facing some reported issues about `NavigationView` with `DataTemplate`s.

Though I'd use `DataTemplateSelector` for your case and the best thing is that this works.

Here is the code:

**MenuItemDataTemplateSelector.cs**

```cs
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace WinUI3NavigationViewTest;

public class MenuItemDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate? CategoryTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate? CarTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override DataTemplate? SelectTemplateCore(object item)
    {
        return item switch
        {
            Category => CategoryTemplate,
            Car => CarTemplate,
            _ => null,
        };
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="WinUI3NavigationViewTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:WinUI3NavigationViewTest"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate
                x:Key="CategoryMenuItemTemplate"
                x:DataType="local:Category">
                <NavigationViewItem
                    Content="{x:Bind Name}"
                    MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind Cars}" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate
                x:Key="CarMenuItemTemplate"
                x:DataType="local:Car">
                <NavigationViewItem Content="{x:Bind Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
            <local:MenuItemDataTemplateSelector
                x:Key="ItemTemplateSelector"
                CarTemplate="{StaticResource CarMenuItemTemplate}"
                CategoryTemplate="{StaticResource CategoryMenuItemTemplate}" />
        </Grid.Resources>
        <NavigationView
            MenuItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource ItemTemplateSelector}"
            MenuItemsSource="{x:Bind Categories}" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```